# Boot rails 3.1 in different environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment, production-environment

Trying to boot a Rails 3.1 app locally in production mode.

```
rails s
```

will boot into development just fine. When I try

```
rails s production
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in
  `require': no such file to load -- rack/handler/production (LoadError)
      from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in `try_require'
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Apparently the correct command is

```
rails s -e production
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the "-e" wasn't previously required.

Comment: When i do this I get other errors instead, e.g. "Stack level too deep". What is the -e thing? Not "ignore errors" I presume?

Comment: "Stack level too deep" probably means you have a recursive function that never returns. The "-e" is for "environment".